# MIPS Assembly accessing an array while using a variable as the offset

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips, offset

Is there anyway to use a variable as the offset number for an array? For example, I know the normal offset and array works like this:

```
ARRAY: .word 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
lw $t6, ARRAY
lw $t7, 0($t6)
```

Where the index at zero would be loaded into t7, but what I want to do is this:

```
 ARRAY: .word 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
 lw $t6, ARRAY
 li $t7, 0
 lw $t8, $t7($t6)
```

This way I could increment the variable t7 as I wanted to in code without having to hard-code the offset. I keep getting a syntax error, so I guess what I am trying to do is wrong. Is there anyway I can do something like this so that I can increment the index of the array?

Comment: This is not supported. But since MIPS has plenty of general-purpose registers you can just sum `$t6` and `$t7` into a free register and keep incrementing that. And you don't have to guess whether something you're doing is supported; _MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers
Volume II: The MIPS32™ Instruction Set_ lists all available instructions and their expected operands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to increment through an array with a variable, you must use this setup:

```
ARRAY: .word 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
li $t2, 0
lw $t3, ARRAY($t2)
addi $t2, $t2, 1
```

Comment: Note that unless the address of `ARRAY` is somewhere in the range 0xFFFF8000-0x00007FFF, that `lw` instruction of yours will not be directly encodable as a MIPS instruction. The assembler might still accept it as a _pseudo-instruction_, which it will translate into 2 or more actual MIPS instructions. You can easily see this in a simulator like SPIM or MARS.